# Understanding a discrepancy in tensor multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, quantum-computation, tensor-rank

I have seen in texts about quantum computing people take two vectors and do tensor multiplication. Now, what confuses me is that vectors are (1,0)-tensors. This means that when I multiply two of them, I get a (2,0)-tensor. However, they treat the result as a vector, that is (1,0)-tensor, which should be a type error as far as I can see.

Could someone explain where is the mistake?

Comment: Can you post a link with an example?

Comment: Note that a tensor product is again a vector, in the tensor product of the vector spaces.

Comment: When we speak of tensors of type $(p, q)$, this is with respect to a fixed vector space, say $V$. If you take the tensor product of two vectors, it will be a $(2,0)$-tensor with respect to $V$, but at the same time a vector with respect to $V\otimes V$.

Comment: ... in other words, the tensor product of two vectors is a vector each of whose components is itself a vector.

Comment: (1,0) and (0,1) tensors are **uni-indexed** linear combinations but (2,0), (1,1) and (0,2) are **bi-indexed** linear combinations. (3,0),(2,1),(1,2) and (0,3) are ...